# Why I can't login to my Mac without typing in my password sometimes?

Tags: mac, password, touch-id

In 99% of the time, I can log in to my sleeping Mac (M1 MacBook Air) using TouchID. But sometimes it shows that 'password is required to log in' screen, and the TouchID seems to be not working.

This is a very minor issue that I don't care about that much, but I wonder why this happens and also want to know if there is any way to prevent it. I haven't 'mistouched' the TouchID button a few times nor has no one except me tried to log in using TouchID.

Comment: besides the [current answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/426494/116013), there must be some random challenges being thrown out, or extra triggering conditions, because it sometimes happen for no discernible reason.  Note that a mac can **sneakily** reboot itself, and pretend nothing happened, for example with a glitch from its [T2 security chip - "kernel: (AppleSMC) Previous shutdown cause: -20"](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/How+to+determine+Mac+shutdown+causes/119528), but that is covered under the given answer (*after you restart*).

Answer (score 4):

Apple documents this here:

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204587

A quotation from the article:

> To start using Touch ID, you must first set up a passcode on your
> iPhone or iPad (or a password on your Mac). You must enter your
> passcode or password for additional security validation:
>
> - after you restart your iPhone, iPad, or Mac;
> - when more than 48 hours have passed from the last time you unlocked your device;
> - to add or delete a fingerprint to use with Touch ID;
> - to change the iPhone or iPad passcode or Mac system password, and for other security settings like FileVault on your Mac;
> - when there have been more than five unrecognized Touch ID authorization attempts in a row;
> - and after you log out of your Mac.

Comment: Ah, so it is 2 days, same as iOS, which will be why mine didn't trigger this morning. I can lose my answer now we have a definitive citation. Well found.

Comment: There must be other triggers as it has asked even when none of those are true…

Comment: @SolarMike I agree. None of these apply in my case, but it still keeps happening.